# Can I use RegNotifyChangeKeyValue to track changes to a value of a Registry key?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I've been trying to adjust the example of uisng RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)for my particular case -- i.e. tracking changes done to a value within a registry key, but the event used in the example fires only once right after the app starts.

So I was wondering, can I track changes done to values of a Registry key like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on that page from MSDN you mentioned, you can find that using `REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET` as a filter does the following:

> "Notify the caller of changes to a value of the key. This can include
>   adding or deleting a value, or changing an existing value."

Further down it says:

> This function detects a single change. After the caller receives a
>   notification event, it should call the function again to receive the
>   next notification.

You need to call `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` in a loop in order to catch further changes.

Comment: Thanks. That API is quite a handful. I generally try to avoid APIs that have several paragraphs in remarks...

Comment: Why? The more documentation, the better! I always appreciate when API is well documented.

Comment: Yes, only if all MS APIs worked the same. In my experience, most of that Remarks stuff is just a bunch of poorly documented warnings of what could go wrong with their APIs.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft's API is not perfect and documentation is sometimes ambiguous and incomplete but use to the maximum what's offered - anything's better than nothing :)

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate your input!